# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't show when called by method "show"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI 1.10.3 and jQuery 1.8.3.

Whenever I click the input field, the datepicker shows and everthing works fine. **But** whenever I click the the `<a>` element the datepicker is shown for a millisecond before dying with the javascript error:

> TypeError: i is undefined

What could be the problem? The initialized datepicker works fine but when called by the method "show" it seems to die.

The HTML (simplified for this example):

```
<div id="datefield">
    <input type="text" readonly="true" />
    <a href="#">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

The JavaScript (simplified for this example):

```
$("#datefield input").datepicker();

$("#datefield a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#datefield input").datepicker('show');
});
```

**Update 2:** Removed the options variable in the datepicker call, for clarity. It was not the cause of the error

Comment: Here is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/t3QLP/; what have you set up in the __option__ var?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Just some onSelect logic, which works fine, and worked fine before I added the <a>. Also, I see you have a different jQuery UI version than me in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you post your onSelect function? With 1.10.3 is the same http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/t3QLP/1/

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward It's fairly long so I removed it completely and I still had the same problem. Working in the inputfield but failing on the <a> tag.

Comment: Can you share it on jsfiddle? Or in a live site?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward Sadly I can't share it since it's in a closed web application. I suspect that it isn't the actual code I posted that's wrong but something "around" it, for instance conflicting js scripts, mismatches jquery/ui versions etc.

Comment: It's difficult to tell, if you can provide more context I'll help you out

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9HEDA/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#datefield input").datepicker();

   $("#datefield a").click(function () {
      $("#datefield input").datepicker("show");
   }); 
});
```

Removing the options from firstline of you js code worked for me.
Where did you define options?

Comment: I added a comment about the options variable in my OP.

Comment: I see, someone already posted a similar ans in comments a min earlier :)
By the way, I am not able to reproduce your error. Can you try creating a fiddle that throws the same error?

Comment: I actually can't reproduce it on jsfiddle. I suspect it's something to do with either my jquery/ui versions not being compatible or maybe it's failing because it's conflicting with other javascript or something. But basically I'm lost.

Comment: Try using the "showon:'button'" option and see if its conflicting with your other js code.

http://jsfiddle.net/9HEDA/1/

You can give your <i></i> tag instead of <div>